# Create mutiple Configurations form and grid

Tags: grid, forms, multiselect

I want to create form with the multiple select data in the multiple tabs and also create grid.

The screenshot of the from and grid is attached with the message:
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you explain me. you want to save data in the database when multi-selected item